# Use of the word 'Salve' as a remedy

Tags: word-usage

I've used the word 'salve' in one writing I've made. One of the readers objects that the word 'salve' is 'a substance we use for healing a wound' thus it can't be used here. My sentence was:

---

Supplication is a salve for every sore.

---

Although when I used it, the thing I had in my mind was that here the word 'salve' is in a 'figurative' sense. I need to have some inputs from the contributors on this with some examples.

Comment: Salve can be used figuratively, e.g "when someone is upset or sad, kind words can be a salve for their feelings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*salve*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salve):

> **2** : a remedial or soothing influence or agency
>   // a *salve* to their hurt feelings

And from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/salve):

> **1.1** Something that is soothing or consoling for wounded feelings or an uneasy conscience.
>   ‘the idea provided him with a salve for his guilt’

Using it in this second sense of the word is perfectly fine. Point the person who objects to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem. You have formed an expression which is grammatical, whose meaning is clear, and which I understood.

The word "salve" is no longer in common usage, at least in American English, and less-educated speakers may not recognize it; but it seems to me to be used correctly. The word "supplication" is not in common usage outside religious contexts. Neither of these facts mean your expression is wrong; I only point them out so you can judge whether it is appropriate for your context and your audience.